# svg.js not working with Typescript and Stencil.js

Tags: typescript, svg.js, stenciljs

I have a basic Stencil app built with Typescript.
I'm not using Angular.
I'm unable to use svg.js.

Here is my full Component:

```
import { Component, State } from '@stencil/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';

@Component({
  tag: 'astro-sandbox',
  styleUrl: 'sandbox.css'
})
export class AstroSandbox {
  componentDidLoad() {
    // console.info(SVG)
    let drawing = SVG('drawing');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="drawing">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This fails with `{ Error: Cannot call a namespace ('SVG')...`

I tried looking at SVG with `console.info('SVG')` and it compiles but the browser gives me the error
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'SVG' of undefined`.

I know that my app works and I got moment.js working no problem, so there's not a TS config issue. Intellisense for svg.js in VS Code is also working.

Comment: For some reason that import does not work correctly. Try import SVG from svg.js or use require.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in svg.js. You can see the corresponding issue [here](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/866). The problem is, that svg.js adds itself to `this`. In ECMAscript 262 `this` is undefined in this context to prevent littering the window object. For the meantime you can use the code of this PR: https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/pull/867